# 1D Harmonic Oscillator: Eigenstate (|x=0>) at position x=0

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

Given an harmonic oscillator I need to calculate the eigenvector $|x=0\rangle$.
Knowing that 
$$x|x=0\rangle = 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad (a + a^\dagger) | x = 0 \rangle = 0 $$
I started to plug in the matrix notation
$$\begin{pmatrix}  0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots \\
  1 & 0 & \sqrt 2 & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & \sqrt 2 & 0 & \sqrt 3 & \cdots \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
  c_0 \\ c_1 \\ c_2 \\ \cdots
\end{pmatrix} = 0 $$
Now I want to get the $c_i$ values to get an expression for the ket, but I am kind of stuck.
I started to normalize 
$$ \frac{c_0}{N} = 1 $$ 
and got some expression for the eigenket
$$ |x=0\rangle = N \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ - \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \\ 0 \\ \left(- \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \right) \left(- \frac{\sqrt 3}{\sqrt 4} \right) \\ \cdots \end{pmatrix}$$

**Now I would like to know how to continue? Or if there is a different way to solve this problem?**

I am also a little bit insecure about the normalization:
Regarding
$$N^2 \cdot \vec c^2 = N^2 \cdot \left( 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{8} + \cdots \rightarrow \infty\right)= 1 \quad \Rightarrow \quad N \to 0$$
So it seems that I cannot normalize the function probperly.

Comment: Yes. I don't think $x$ eigenkets are normalizable. You can check this by looking at $\langle x' | {\hat x} | x \rangle$ and simplifying it in two ways which then implies $(x-x') \langle x' | x \rangle = 0$. This implies that $\langle x' | x \rangle  \propto \delta(x-x')$. Thus, they are $\delta$-function normalizable.